# WM_SETREDRAW and losing z-order/focus

Tags: .net, winapi

I have a .NET application with a skinning library (Devexpress) and a MDI parent form.

When I add child forms, I use **WM_SETREDRAW** to disable painting for performance reasons.

However, after setting **WM_SETREDRAW** to 1 again and calling **refresh** on the MDI parent, the main form loses its z-order and is on the background on my desktop.

I have to call **BringToFront** or **Focus** then, but there is still a short time period (<1s) in which my application "vanishes" for the user.

Is there a better way to disable redrawing but keeping the form visible?

Comment: Strange.  Are you sure you are not also tinkering with the Enabled property?  That would explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem comes from this remark in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145219.aspx):

> If the application sends the `WM_SETREDRAW` message to a hidden window, the window becomes visible (that is, the operating system adds the `WS_VISIBLE` style to the window).

Since [a hidden window is effectively disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599#visibility) (although it can still process messages, it cannot receive user input), this causes you to run afoul of the correct order for enabling and disabling windows. When the currently focused window becomes disabled (and therefore loses the focus), the focus has to go *somewhere* because it can't be nowhere.

It's hard to say *exactly* what's happening your case without seeing the code. I'm also not entirely sure from your question whether you're sending the `WM_SETREDRAW` message to the MDI parent or the MDI child. But I *can* say that skinning libraries are notorious for screwing things up and causing nightmarish bugs. Ask yourself whether you really need such a thing in the first place, and whether it's really worth the struggle.

I also have to question the underlying motivation:

> When I add child forms, I use `WM_SETREDRAW` to disable painting for performance reasons.

There shouldn't be any painting or performance problems when adding child forms, assuming that you do all of your initialization inside of the form's constructor, rather than some other method. That ensures that everything gets initialized properly *before* the form is displayed, and there's no need for multiple redraws. Everything gets drawn exactly once, the first time that the form is displayed, which is exactly the same thing that happens in the ideal case with `WM_SETREDRAW`: it gets drawn only once after you enable redrawing.